# How to view the comment from specflow test case in visual studio test explorer's test log?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, specflow, test-explorer

Is there any way to view the **tags** and **comments** added in the Specflow's feature file in the Visual Studio Test Explorer's test log output?
I can see the test log output from test explorer by right-clicking on test Detail Summary and clicking **Open test log** option.
My test case is too long, and I need to find out where my test case failed. If there is an option to view comment in the test log output, it would be helpful.

[image: Test explorer Test Detail Summary]

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow does not provide a way to display comments from your feature file in the test log. The [SpecFlow documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Gherkin/Gherkin-Reference.html) does not mention that comments are available in the test log, therefore what you want to do is not possible in SpecFlow.